# OpenGL ES: Combine two Frame Buffer Objects

Tags: opengl-es, framebuffer

I draw two FBO offscreen. Now I wanna overlay them deppending on the depthbuffer values. 
How can I do this?

I found a solution: 
at first I render the depthbuffer in a texture which is attached to the FBO.
second I load it in the fragmentshader to compare the two deptbuffers.
My Fragmentshader looks like this.

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D s_texture1;
uniform sampler2D s_texture2;
uniform sampler2D s_depth1;
uniform sampler2D s_depth2;
void main(){
  vec4 tex1;
  vec4 tex2;
  vec4 depth1;
  vec4 depth2;

  depth1 = texture2D( s_depth1, v_texCoord);
  depth2 = texture2D( s_depth2, v_texCoord);

  tex1 = texture2D( s_texture1, v_texCoord );
  tex2 = texture2D( s_texture2, v_texCoord );
  if ( depth1.r < depth2.r ){
      gl_FragColor = tex1;
  }else{
      gl_FragColor = tex2;
  }
}
```

But it seems like this is not that high-performance.

Is it possible to use a attached renderbuffer in the FBO and access to the data of the renderbuffer in fragmentshader like I do it now?
Would this increase my performance?

Thank you very much.

ragards Mat.

Comment: I don't believe reading from renderbuffer is possible in shader. What you have seems fine to me, is that proven to be not fast enough for you?